# Using each function

Tags: jquery, each

Multiple products per page. I want to display message based on quantity.

```
$j(document).ready(function () {
    $j('#stockqty').text((parseInt($j('#stockqty').text()) > 0) ? "In Stock" : "Out of Stock");
});
```

I've tried this:

```
$j(document).ready(function () {
    $j('#stockqty').each(function () {.text((parseInt($j('#stockqty').text()) > 0) ? "In Stock" : "Out of Stock");
    });
});
```

Just not working.

Comment: What is $j. Maybe to put just $

Comment: `.text` in your `.each` callback needs to be called on something.

Comment: `$j('#stockqty').each` ?? Duplicating the id?

Comment: `$("#someid").each` doesn't make sense, there can be only one `$("#someid")`

Comment: `$('#stockqty')` will only return one element.  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function () {
    $('.stockqty').each(function () {
        parseInt($(this).text()) > 0) ? return "In Stock" : return "Out of Stock");
    });
});
```

Also, there should not be multiple elements with the ID of "stockqty".  Consider changing that to class="stockqty" (subsequently using the corresponding jQuery selector).

Additionally, although I have used a *return* statement in the above code, it is possible that you might want to instead append a value to the user interface.  You can do this through something like:

```
$('#resultArea').html("In Stock") : $('#resultArea').html("Out of Stock");
```

Lastly, it's perfectly acceptable to just do

```
$(function() {
```

instead of

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

(Note: the commonly used jQuery symbol is "$", unless you previously passed in "$j" as a parameter.)

Comment: Thanks, that all makes perfect sense. I should of realized the ID thing, but still no joy. Fiddler seems to have a problem with it also.

Comment: Can you post a link to your fiddle?

Comment: I still saw a few syntax issues with your code (in addition, there was no HTML).  I chose to go with jQuery 1.10, as well, instead of what you were using (1.7).  See this [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5wf48/1/)